# Can I access a string value from resource dll in windows phone 7 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization

OK, so I've successfully managed to create a localisation resource library for the title of my WP7 app using the msdn [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967550%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

The app title is therefore stored in a string table within the resource library AppResLib.dll. This resource string is accessible from the WMAppManifest.xml file by using the following code:

@AppResLib.dll,-200

I would like to know if it's possible to access the app title string from a class within my app? My google searches seem to suggest that it's not possible. It's not possible to use a solution as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411377/get-the-windows-phone-7-application-title-from-code), as it just returns the string "@AppResLib.dll,-200".

I think the only solution is to define the app title a second time in a localised string resource file as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) which I would prefer not to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm use localised ressources, but it's a ressource file, I want to call my labels, title, and other text ressourecs in all my application (in my c# class and in XAML) .

if you want tutorial ( in french, sorry ) is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pierreca/archive/2010/09/21/internationalisez-votre-application-windows-phone-7.aspx) (you want to use [google translate](http://translate.google.com) for translate all page in english )

Comment: Hi Doc Roms, thanks for the reply. Yes I am already using localised resources using a resource file, however, you can't use this file to set the application and tile name in WMAppManifest.xml?